# Nuget - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package

I have a problem with nuget package manager in vs 2015.
Some packages like Unity has been installed with no problem.
Some packages like EF had problems while installing. 
Some packages like Automapper had the same problem but when I installed another version of this package, It installed fine.

here is the output:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.


at NuGet.Protocol.Core.v3.GlobalPackagesFolderUtility.<AddPackageAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at NuGet.Protocol.Core.v3.DownloadResourceV3.<GetDownloadResourceResultAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.PackageDownloader.<GetDownloadResourceResultAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<ExecuteNuGetProjectActionsAsync>d__42.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<ExecuteNuGetProjectActionsAsync>d__42.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.<ExecuteActionsAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.<PerformActionAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
========== Finished ==========
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive

Comment: I try to say it breifly. but what description I should tell?

Comment: Give more information about what the problem is, what type of project do you have etc

Comment: The problem is nuget doesn't work correctly. Sometimes there is no problem with some packages, sometimes it has problem with some packages to install, but there is no reason!!! the only error is what I told above. But I think this isn't a problem of vs or project type, becuase I had the same problem with nuget console outside of vs.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is a common problem with the use of the new protocol (version 3) nuget used in Visual Studio 2015. It is with multiple nuget packages, for example Microsoft.Owin 3.0.1. 
To fix this go to:

```
C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Roaming\NuGet
```

And edit the XML configuration file, commenting the line of protocol 3:

```
<!-- add key = "nuget.org" value = "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion = "3" /-->
<add key = "nuget.org" value = "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
```

Maintenance settings for version 2. Save and restart visual studio 2015. You should now restore the nuget packages without problems.

Answer (score 17):

Same problem still exists in Visual Studio 2022. The solution:

1. Navigate to C:\Users<your user name>\AppData\Roaming\NuGet // remember AppData is a hidden folder, so you will have to make Windows show hidden files and folders before you can see it
2. Open NuGet.Config in Notepad (or whatever will let you edit it)
3. In the "packageSources" section, look for the line:

> add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"
> protocolVersion="3"

and delete 'protocolVersion="3"'

4. Save the file and restart Visual Studio 2022

Comment: Excellent, thanks @Will. I'm so used to NuGet running smoothly that it's a shock when something like this happens.

Comment: Thanks. 
Also, right after fixing this issue with this solution, I fell into another issue around package sources, which got fixed with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55483821/8326848.

Answer (score 2):

When i've had Nuget problems in the past these are the steps i've done:

1) Use Nuget package manager to remove out of project(s)

2) Clean and Build (you'll have errors because you do longer have the references
2) Make sure the packages were removed from your packages.config (if not, delete and repeat step 2)

3) Make sure the .dlls were removed from your bin folder (if not, delete and repeat step 2)

4) Add packages back in and rebuild.  Ensure the packages were added to packages.config (with appropriate version) and .dlls were added back to the bin folder (with appropriate version).

Comment: The problem is I never installed them, there is no packages.config and there is no another assembly of the package!! I have 7 project in my solution and diffrent packages in each of them.

Comment: The avoid the problem 4), you can use Project Dependency Browser (http://projectdependencybrowser.org) which can analyze a C# project for NuGet/DLL referencing problems...

Answer (score 0):

I am running VS 2017, but was having this error with the TFS build server during the "dotnet restore" task.  The issue was we had an internal local file share, but the nuget.config had protocolVersion="3" for that entry.  After removing that property, the build was successful.

Answer (score 0):

1. My problem happens in `NuGet.Config`
   (he `NuGet.Config` file path: `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\NuGet`)
2. Reason：*Tools* -> *NuGet Package Manager* -> *Package Management Settings* -> *Package Source* ->

   ```
   nuget.org=https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
   ```

   The default package source has attribute `protocolVersion="3"`，but I modified it to my offline package source, meanwhile creating a new package source：

   ```
   nuget.ort=https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
   ```

   The new package source has no attribute `protocolVersion="3"`,so I always fail to install packages whether of online or offline.
3. Solution: Add `ProtocolVersion="3"` to

   ```xml
   <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3"/>
   ```

   and remove `ProtocolVersion="3"` in my offline package source.