# NuGet Package Manager not searching or installing on VS2015 - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package

I have visual studio 2015 community edition and I am trying to use the NuGet package manger to install HTML Agility Pack into my project.

Firstly, the search wasn't working and I could not install it via command line also. So, I uninstalled the extension and re-installed it and still doesn't work.

Here's the screenshot of search not working and command line install failure:

[image]

```
PM> Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack
Install-Package : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33269430/nuget-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object/33879114#33879114

Answer (score 11):

Fix :

1. Close your Visual Studio.
2. Navigate to %AppData%\NuGet\ folder
3. Delete the NuGet.config file
4. Now open Visual Studio. You can notice that a new NuGet.Config file is generated

Issue will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the Nuget Package Manager. I experienced this issue after updating to Visual Studio 2015 Update 2

This can be done via `Tools > Extensions and Updates`

Answer (score 1):

My issue is kind of similar to this one, search wasn't working but console was working fine without error.

I figured out a workaround, if you've never modified your personal `NuGet.config` file at `%appdata%\nuget\` or never customized your NuGet sources, delete the file then restart Visual Studio, this will trigger the NuGet extension to create a fresh copy of the default `NuGet.config` file, and search functionality will work again as supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the NuGet Package, it worked for me once.

Comment: this is a blank project with no nuget packages loaded into it. I have nothing to update. I am trying to install a new package into a blank project.

Answer (score 0):

In `'Package source:'`, select `'All'` or `'nuget.org'`.